# how to organize a notification from the server to the client for android?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an application that works with php api. I need to implement a notification clients about any event. I decided to treat every minute in php in service. if something has changed - notify the client. but I think it's not right. if ten clients access the server as the server will understand who read the message and who is not. Correctly - the server must send notice to the client

Comment: use Google GCM notifications for this

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is Google Cloud messaging.

Here is the reference link for your understanding
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Mark as right if this what you want.

Comment: thanks for the link. something like that, but if there is something simpler? I will have 10 clients in all. may have a simple solution?

Comment: You can look into the parse push notifications, it also works on GCM but is very easy to implement in app.
try this link https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android

Comment: it really can not be done without the use of third-party services? I have a php server. if it made a new notice must be android